# What are the uses of these in an .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(robots\.txt|[a-z0-9_\-]*sitemap[a-z0-9_\.\-]*\.(xml|xsl|html)(\.gz)?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|avif|avifs|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|webp|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|webm|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wma|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

is this related to endurance page cache ?

Comment: That lists a number of conditions under which nothing should be done. Unless there's more to it that you aren't sharing, it seems completely pointless.

Comment: See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#:~:text=to%20use%20them-,.,directory%2C%20and%20all%20subdirectories%20thereof.

Comment: What do you mean by "this"? Which kind of "endurance page cache" do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` file allows you to override some of the global server configuration. Some common uses of the `.htaccess` file include:

- **URL rewriting**: You can use mod_rewrite to rewrite URL requests.
- **Access control**: You can restrict or allow access to specific directories or files based on various criteria.
- **Custom error pages**: You can configure your own error pages for common HTTP errors such as 404, 403, or 500.
- **Mime types**: You can define specific MIME types for file extensions.
- **Server-side includes (SSI)**: You can enable server-side includes to dynamically include the contents of one file into another.
- **Caching and compression**: You can enable browser caching and server-side compression.

It's important to note that not all web servers support the `.htaccess` file, as it's specific to Apache.